# Phantom do not get HTML from site, only get source code

Tags: javascript, html, renderscript

I want to get page html after javascript run from instagram. So i use phantom to do that. Below code can render an image of the page after all javascript run. But i can not get the html content. It only gives source codes with javascript but do not give the rendered html. Can you help me?

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var url = 'some instagram post';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    setTimeout(function(status) {
        page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla';
        page.evaluate(function(){});
        page.render('image.png');
        fs.write('output.html', page.content, 'w');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
});
```